# "gh auth login --with-token <Token>" asks to paste token

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to use `gh login auth --with-token <token>` in a GitHub Actions workflow to run other workflows from this workflow, but getting error, prompts for token asks to paste the token.

How should I pass the token?

Comment: Please provide code and the error. Are you using the token in the url?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I suggest reading [this article](https://josh-ops.com/posts/gh-auth-login-in-actions/). The first example is literally what you're looking for, the other examples are alternatives using env variables or the Github App.

Answer (score 0):

You can find on the [GitHub CLI command documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) a hint regarding how to perform this operation on Github Actions:

> To use gh in GitHub Actions, add GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }} to env.

As well as on the [Github Actions official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows):

> GitHub CLI is preinstalled on all GitHub-hosted runners. For each step that uses GitHub CLI, you must set an environment variable called GH_TOKEN to a token with the required scopes.

There are also good examples in [this article](https://josh-ops.com/posts/gh-auth-login-in-actions/) (I recommend the lecture).

**Example 1:**

```
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | gh auth login --with-token
        # use another gh cli command line
```

**Example 2:**

```
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
    - run: |
        # use gh cli command line
```

Comment: I used this  `run: |
          
            echo "Running $workflow"
            gh workflow run $workflow -R Repo -f Project_ID=${{ github.event.inputs.Project_ID }} -f Cluster_Name=${{ github.event.inputs.Cluster_Name }} -f PERFORM_UNINSTALL=${{ github.event.inputs.PERFORM_UNINSTALL }}
          done
        env:
          PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT }} `
but still getting 'Run for workflow in $(ls .github/workflows/*.yaml); do
Running .github/workflows/abc.yaml
Welcome to GitHub CLI!

To authenticate, please run `gh auth login`
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.`

Comment: The env variable needs to be named `GH_TOKEN`, you can't use another value.